# wsimport problem with Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, webservice-client, wsimport

I am generating a web service client using wsimport but I get an error like this

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at sun.net.www.ParseUtil.toURI(ParseUtil.java:261)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:905)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:836)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1172)
        at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.DOMForest.parse(DOMForest.java:222)
        at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.DOMForest.parse(DOMForest.java:139)
        at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.MetadataFinder.parseWSDL(MetadataFinder.java:91)
        at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.WSDLParser.parse(WSDLParser.java:130)
        at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.buildModel(WSDLModeler.java:115)
        at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.run(WsimportTool.java:172)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.Invoker.invoke(Invoker.java:105)
        at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.WsImport.main(WsImport.java:41)

Any cluees or any idea ?

Edwin jaws
TIA

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's something wrong with the URL for the WSDL; a NullPointerException sounds like it's completely missing. Perhaps your command line is not being parsed the way you think it is.

How do you call wsimport? Using what parameters? Via Windows command line, Ant script or Linux shell?

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me, then I realised that I had a malformed URL. Please check it.